# Minecraft window is acting strange - can't be maximised?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, windows-8

I was playing Minecraft and tried to take a screenshot but pressed <kbd>F11</kbd> and ever since, my window has been acting weird, not like the normal windows 8 window.

The restore/maximise button is grayed out and I can't just drag it to the top of my screen to make it bigger.

---

Unlike in the duplicate question, it did **not** return to normal when I closed out of Minecraft and reopened it. Is there any other way to fix this issue?

Comment: I don't see the dupe question. Also, I think this is a bug with Windows 8

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem a few days ago.

Go into settings, then video settings and there should be an option that says like "start as maximized" (sorry I'm not at my computer right now so I don't know the exact wording). By selecting that option it should toggle to windowed mode. Now if you restart Minecraft you can change the window size.

You can also press <kbd>F11</kbd> to go back into full screen mode but unless you started minecraft in windowed mode you won't be able to change the size if you go back to windowed mode.

Answer (score -1):

The F11 key toggles full screen. Just press F11 again